# EasyMock, andReturn a capture

Tags: easymock

suppose I want to mock a method with the following signature:

```
public A foo(A a)
```

I want foo to be mocked in a way that it returned what it received (that is the same instance a)

I tried unsuccessfully the following:

```
Capture<A> capture = new Capture();
expect(myclass.foo(capture)).andReturn(capture.getValue());
```

This does not work because the capture is still empty when getValue() is called.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```java
public class A {

    public <A> A foo(A a) {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        A mock = createNiceMock(A.class);

        expect(mock.foo(anyObject())).andAnswer(new IAnswer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object answer() throws Throwable {
                return EasyMock.getCurrentArguments()[0];
            }
        }).anyTimes();

        replay(mock);

        System.out.println(mock.foo("1"));
        System.out.println(mock.foo(2L));
    }
}
```

Prints out:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Looks a bit too complex. Is there not an easier way?

Comment: you could extract answer to your own class.

Comment: Example of extracting to separate class:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667172/how-can-i-mock-a-method-in-easymock-that-shall-return-one-of-its-parameters

Define it once, then everywhere you want to use it you just say expect(...).andAnswer(new ArgumentAnswer<T>())

Comment: You can also use your capture within the IAnswer, to save some potential casting and editing argument position in two places.  In that case, it should also be possible to create a generic AnswerWithCapture that works in all cases and takes a Capture instance as a constructor argument.